# Cannot render a list in template from django view

Tags: django, python-3.x

All my views are being rendered properly but when i try to render a list using iteration nothing is displayed on the page, without error.

the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from haleys_chemist.models import anti_bacterials
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .table import anti_bacterials_Table
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import notepadform
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required 
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView


class retriever(TemplateView):
    template_name='index.html'
    def expiry_days(self,request):
        expired_drugs= anti_bacterials.objects.all()
        args={'expired_drugs':expired_drugs}
        return render (request, self.template_name,args)
```

template(index.html):

```
                              <h6><i>Drugs about to expire</i></h6>                                
                                {%for expired_drug in expired_drugs%}
                                <ul>
                                    <li>{{expired_drug.Drug_name}}</li>
                                    <li>{{expired_drug.expiry_date}}</li>
                                </ul>
                                {%endfor%}
                            </div>
```

model:

```
class anti_bacterials(models.Model):
    Drug_id= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True);
    Drug_name= models.CharField(max_length=50);
    expiry_date= models.DateField();
    Price_per_mg= models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
```

i need to list the expired drugs on the left bar. i know i have queried for all objects on the view but still i should get a list of all the objects names and expiry dates.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the generic `TemplateView` properly.

The method `expiry_days` will never be called because the generic `TemplateView` doesn't know about it.

Simply you can use the method `get_context_data` to achieve what you want:

```
class retriever(TemplateView):
    template_name='index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['expired_drugs']= anti_bacterials.objects.all()
        return context
```

Read more about the generic `TemplateView` [in Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) and [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/).